# Why can't I see my taken pictures in gallery?

Tags: android, camera, android-sdcard, fileoutputstream

I am experimenting with the Camera on my non-rooted 4.0.4 Android device having no sd-card. I am doing some burst-shots and saving them on the internal memory.

My problem is that my photos get stored in `/data/data/my.package.name/files` which I cannot access without root-permission. I can see the files, but they have no read-permission.

I found some broadcast-Intent that should make them visible in the standard-gallery, but that doesn't seem to work neither.

*Does anyone have another idea of how I can access my photos? Or tweak the stuff I tried so far?*

how I save the photos:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {           
            Log.i(TAG, ""+Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));           
            Log.i(TAG,"fotofolder is "+getFilesDir());

            // write to local sandbox file system
             outStream = CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg",
             System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);

            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();

       //this intent should make fotos visible in the gallery
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,                           
                     Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                    // Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

            Log.i(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
     ...
}
```

the log:

```
08-23 12:42:49.324: I/FrontCamera(15832): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures
08-23 12:42:49.327: I/FrontCamera(15832): fotofolder is /data/data/com.example.camera/files
08-23 12:42:49.370: I/FrontCamera(15832): onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: 430493
```

<--- it puts the photos to the `data/data...` folder, instead of the useful `mnt/sdcard/Pictures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MediaStore.Images.Media](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imageBitmap, imageTitle, imageDescription);
```

you can use the [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) for saving.

Answer (score 1):

**To reflect image in gallery  try this:**

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(DetailsActivity.this, new String[] {filepath }, null, new OnScanCompletedListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                                                }
                                            });
```

Comment: photos are in gallery by now. was just the missing sd-card messing with me